# How to set black background in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, color-scheme

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2 with the Darkula color scheme but the contrast is too low for me, so I want to set the background color to pure black (#000000). While there are options to set the background of the console and the editor to black, this does not apply to the rest of the user interface. How can I change the background color of the whole theme (console, editor, menu, dialogs,...) to black?

Answer (score 15):

From the menu bar, open the settings dialog:
`File` -> `Settings` (`Preferences` for Mac OS)

**Change background of code editor:**

In the list menu on the left, go to:

`Editor` -> `Colors & Fonts` -> `General`

Then, in the menu on the right, go to:

`Text` -> `Default Text` and select the `Background` checkbox.

**Change background of console:**

In the list menu on the left, go to:

`Editor` -> `Console Colors`

Then, in the menu on the right:

Select `Background` and Click the checkbox for `Background`

PS: you might need to "Save as" the default scheme before that, then choose the background color. As it mightn't allow you to modify stock schemes/themes.

It's also possible to do stuff by language etc, but it surely could've been made easier.

Works on version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
Build #IC-162.2032.8, built on September 9, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b343 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Comment: I am using 2016.3.4, for me the console background was under Editor -> Colors & fonts -> console colors -> console -> background

Answer (score 7):

Check this list of the themes, some of them are pure black

> https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes

UPDATE: As of 2018.3, IDEA has its own high contrast theme. You can access in in

> Settings → Appearance & Behavior

[image]

The example of the theme is here:

[image]

In this version, they added also better support for screen readers, you can lear more [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/10/intellij-idea-2018-3-eap-high-contrast-theme-and-more-accessibility-improvements/).

Comment: this thing is amazing on glossy notebook screens

Comment: Quick question: the background on the projects (left side) is dark black, the background on editor (right side) is gray-black - lighter than left side. How do I make the right side to be as dark as left side?

Comment: Not sure, but as a workaround, you can set editor background image as solid black image? It is under Settings -> Appearance.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am trying to find a way to change the color for the actual High contrast theme (in the config or wherever this color is set).

Comment: Found it: Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->General->Default Text. Change background color to 000000

Comment: @Andrey Works, thanks! The column with line numbers is still grey though, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

An updated answer for the latest versions, follow the steps:

```
Preferences | Editor | Colors Scheme | General | Text | Default text | Background
```

In the `Background` set the color to hex value `00000`.